# Problems with JS Interop when compiled to javascript

Tags: dart, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as my server solution. I'm loading their framework.js in my dart.html header section.

First of all, everything(CRUD) works great running in Dartium.
Now my goal is to make it work compiled to javascript as well.

First thing I need to do is make login work. The Parse JS for initialization and logging in is as follow:

```javascript
Parse.initialize("appid", "appkey");

Parse.User.logIn("myname", "mypass", {
  success: function(user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
});
```

And here is my updated attempt in Dart. I'm not running with the minified option.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {

  js.context.Parse.initialize("appid", "appkey");

  js.context.Parse.User.logIn("myname","mypass", js.map({
    "success": new js.Callback.once((user){
      print("success");
    }),
    "error": new js.Callback.once((user, error){
      print("error");
    }),
  }));
}
```

It's working great in Dartium and prints "success".

When compiled to javascript I get this error in Safari: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

The full error in Google Chrome console looks like this:

Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON js.dart:1043
$.Proxy__forward js.dart:1043
$$.Proxy.noSuchMethod$1 js.dart:1033 (anonymous function)
$.main tabort.dart:21
$.main0 tabort.html_bootstrap.dart:8
$$._IsolateContext.eval$1 isolate_helper.dart:265
$.startRootIsolate isolate_helper.dart:89 (anonymous function)
 tabort.html_bootstrap.dart.js:13949

Help, or pointing me in the right direction would be very appreciated!

**EDIT:** Downloaded the latest continuous build: 0.1.2_r22610. **Now everything works!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Dart* code corresponding to this *JS* code :

```javascript
Parse.User.logIn("myname", "mypass", {
  success: function(user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
});
```

is :

```dart
js.context.Parse.User.logIn("myname", "mypass", js.map({
  'success': new js.Callback.once((user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  }),
  'error': new js.Callback.once((user, error) {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  })
}));
```

If you compile your *Dart* code to *JS* don't use the *--minify* option because of [issue 9283](http://dartbug.com/9283).

**EDIT** : Your problem ( *JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures* ) should disappear starting from r22598 (see https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/zZ8Sx5rojis/UddCmmnaYTkJ)

Comment: Thank you! I corrected my code to your suggestion. It still gives me this error: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

Comment: I don't know if there's a relation, but I face a bug on google maps because some JS object contains a "___dart_dispatch_record_ZxYxX_0_" as key... I keep on searching and will come back here when I have more informations.

Comment: I should be right. You can track this on https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/zZ8Sx5rojis

Comment: Great news that a fix is on it's way. Thanks again for helping out! Any idea where to follow the progress of r22598?

Comment: I downloaded the latest continuous build 0.1.2_r22610. Now everything works just fine. I will vote up your answer as soon as my reputation is high enough. Thanks again!